# Show an objective function is convex with respect to multiple matrix variables

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-analysis, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

Before go through the details, you can just first consider a toy example $(m,n,N,d_1,d_2)=(2,3,4,1,1)$ which is the simplest case.
I'm solving an optimization problem numerically(probably with Newton's method or BFGS) and proving convergence,
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}\label{}
    & \underset{F\in \mathbb{R}_{m,d_1} G\in \mathbb{R}_{n,d_2}}{\text{minimize}}
    & & \phi(F,G) =\|(L\otimes F)^TVG\|_F^2\\
    & \text{subject to}
    & & \sum_{i=1}^N \|A_i^Tf_j\|_2^2=1 , \ j = 1, \ldots, d_1.\\
    &&& \sum_{i=1}^N \|A_ig_j\|_2^2=1 , \ j = 1, \ldots, d_2. 
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $A_i$'s are known $m$ by $n$ full rank matrices (rank = min{m,n}), and $f_i$, $g_i$ are columns of $F$, $G$ respectively.
$L$ is a known $N$ by $N$ matrix. $V = [A_1^T\  A_2^T\ \ldots \ A_N^T ]^T$
$\otimes$ is the kronecker product (or tensor product)
Define $H=[A_1\  A_2\ \ldots \ A_N ]^T$.
I want to show $\phi$ is convex first, I know it is convex w.r.t F and G separatively, but how to show $\phi$ is convex w.r.t F and G jointly (or nonconvex)?
My thought is to define $x = [\text{vec}(F)^T \text{vec}(G)^T]^T$ and show the hessian matrix(second order derivative w.r.t x) $\succ 0$ (or at least $\succeq$)
After some computations, the hessian would be
\begin{bmatrix}P_{11}&  P_{12}\\ P_{12}^T & P_{22} \end{bmatrix}
where $P_{11}=I\otimes(H(M\otimes GG^T)H^T)$ and $P_{22}=I\otimes(V^T(M\otimes FF^T)V)$
$P_{12}=\sum_{i}\sum_jM_{ij}\{(F^TA_jG)\otimes A_i+ [(F^TA_i)\otimes(A_jG)]K_{n,{d_2}}\} $
where $M=L^TL$ and $K_{m,n}$ is commutation matrix of dimension $mn$ by $mn$ 
Next step is to show $P_{11}-P_{12}P_{22}^{-1}P_{12}^T\succ 0$ (according to thm 1 in [link](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82700609.pdf))
Is there any way to simplify $P_{12}$(I mean replace the double sum with some function of $H$, $V$, and $M$)?
Or is there other way to prove convex or nonconvex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the simplest case, $m = n = d_1 = d_2 = 1$. Then $\phi = L^2V^2F^2G^2$, which is neither jointly convex nor concave in $F$ and $G$ (unless $L$ and/or $V$ are zero, which can't happen due to full rank assumption). Things do not become convex as any of these dimensions increase.

Furthermore, the constraints are nonlinear equality constraints, hence non-convex.

Verdict: This is not a convex optimization problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't notice that one dimensional case, then is there any algorithm can get a converged result with separatively convex function? I need a numerical solution of this problem. Sorry it's my first time to deal with a nonconvex matrix-variable optimization problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need a non-convex nonlinear optimizer. There are both local optimizers and global optimizers, but the latter may take a long time to run, especially if dimensions are not very low. If you use MATLAB, you may find YALMIP to be a convenient way of entering your model, and sparing you the difficulty and error propensity of calculating derivatives.

Comment: I will try YALMIP you recommended also.

Comment: I can calculate derivatives (or gradients) of objective and constraint functions (in this case, it is not so difficult to compute), is that help? I'm not sure descent method or other algorithm will converge. Yes I'm using matlab for simulation but I want some analysis on optimization topic.

Comment: A global optimization algorithm, such as BMIBNB, which is included with YALMIP, should converge to the global optimum, if given enough time (and memory), and if you provide finite lower and upper bounds on all variables. YALMIP will handle all derivatives for you. Some global optimixers, such as BARON (also available under YALMIP) compute all the derivatives internally to the solver. Local optimization solvers, may or may not converge to something, and that something may or mat not be a global optimum, and not necessarily even a local optimum.

Comment: I mean, is there any material talk about algorithms on separately convex function? I want to find some theoretical analysis, like something would be covered in optimization lecture  provided I have computed all the derivatives.

Comment: There is Bi-convex optimization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconvex_optimization and its generalization Multi-convex optimization which is implemented in CVXPY add-on https://github.com/cvxgrp/dmcp .  But your problem does not fall into these due to the nonlinear equality constraints, which are non-convex, even separately in each variable.

Comment: Then what if I change the equality to be $\geq$?

Comment: Needs to be `$\le$ to be convex.

Comment: But if I change = to be $\leq$, the solution would be trivial ($F=0$ or $G=0$)

Comment: That just underscores that you have an inherently very much non-convex problem.

Comment: So typically power constraints are always nonconvex? I just formulate the constraint to let power(or 2-norm) not too small.

Comment: Nonlinear equality constraints are non-convex. if that's what your power constraints are, they are non-convex. I really have no idea whether your stated optimization problem makes any sense for whatever your intended use is  - that is for you to determine.

Comment: okay, I would try something like BMIBNB for simulation this week, thanks you for your advice. It really help me a lot.

Comment: Could I ask you one more question? I don't know how to formulate kronecker product in YALMIP, could you give me some sample?

Comment: kron can be applied to any YALMIP (sfpvar) variables or expressions the same way you would in "regular" MATLAB.  Also note, Gurobi may be another solver you can use to find the global optimum in YALMIP; it can handle non-convex quadratic in objective and/or constraints.